# How to find then-th derative for function f(s)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

[image]

How to calculate the  n-th derative for  f(s)

Comment: You have serious Mathematica format errors, which need to be corrected.  Or, are you asking a mathematics question instead of a Mathematica software question?  if this is a mathematics question, delete it here and report it at the stackexchange mathematics site.

Comment: Since you complained that it is not easy to receive help when a question is closed -and I agree with that- you can spend some time reading the how to ask a good question tutorial https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. In a nutshell, make sure you include proper code in your question, give some background like expected results etc, and make sure to show what precisely is the problem in your mathematica code

Comment: What to ask as question is not the difficulty here for me on this forum , but the presentation is the problem.
I do want to evaluate a complex integral .. i know the answer
Can only redo the question and experiment

Comment: @janamdo perhaps you could post a picture or screenshot of your written problem or code?

Comment: @Adam can you use a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/alx574gc016se4g/afgeleide%20complexe%20functie.png?dl=0) In mathematica  i do want get the same formula ?
`f[s_] := 1/(2 \[Pi] I) Integrate[g[z]/(z - s), z]` ..the startformula for differentiating

Comment: `f[s_] := 1/(2 \[Pi] I) Integrate[g[z]/(z - s), z]` ..i get a menu bar with "pure function" after evaluation f[s_] ` ? 

Probably i must use the commands for to derative this f[s_] function : `D[f[s]^n, {s, n}]`  and forget the pure function option?

Comment: I did evealuate this intergral, but the outcome(out)  in Mathematica does not seem at all as in the pic ( see link)?

Can someone get this in Mathemarica ?

Comment: @adam , got problem with the forum editor for posting a screenshot or picture at start : i was doing this in the markdown editing help and that's why  got only a link 
Now i can add a picture or screenshot in the future in the main editor.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that this question is for here and not [maths site](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

In case you want, indeed, to do it in mathematica, below are some pointers.

You have several issues with the syntax.

To begin with, instead of `f(s)` it should be `f[s]`. Also, you should have used `:=`. Furthermore, don't use `f[s]` on both sides. Anyway, when all is said and done you should have something like this in you notebook.

```
f[s_] := 1/(2 \[Pi] I) Integrate[g[z]/(z - s), z]
```

Now, the way to get the `n-th` derivative is quite straightforward. For a given and explicit function you can do:

```
D[x^n, {x, n}]
```

In this case, similarly, you write

```
D[f[s]^n, {s, n}]
```

Comment: Thanks, @bbgodfrey
Yes it is for Mathematica this question.
Its a while go i used it, so i must learn it again the commands. 
Years ago  i had a book : the student introduction with mathematica with a cd for getting a palette , but nowadays the book  has no software enclosed ?

The suggestion to use also a  real math question website is also very useful , because i am studying complex analyse.
I will execute your commands in Mathematica

Comment: I executed the code from @disposable (thanks) and for f[s_]^n  ..i don't get answer that  i am aspecting
How to show this wanted answer here on forum? 
The answer  from mathematica is split  in a Piecewise for n ?

Comment: Also: Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
Its not easy this